# QGIS Buffer tool: Why do buffers of points not show up?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I've got a point layer and I want to have a very simple buffer around each point.
I have been playing around with different options and all worked somehow except for a flat end cap style. But why is there no buffer drawn for 500 m (=0.5 km) with End cap style "Flat" as shown in the screenshot? The features seem to exist but without any geometry. Is this intended or is it a bug?

[image: No buffer drawn with these settings]

The point layer file can be downloaded here (160kb):
[panama_points.zip](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/files/8730010/panama_points.zip)

Comment: .5 m may be smaller than the "point" you are drawing, may be even subpixel small - what's the scale of your map

Comment: What Ian says. Zoom in very close, then you should see your circles.

Comment: You are right. When doing the screenhot I forgot to put the correct distance unit. I had always tried with 500m aka 0.5 km. I just updated the screenshot and the text so the description should be correct now. Still the same weird result, even when zooming in to the highest degree. As soon as the "End cap style" option is switched to any other value and the Buffer processing is executed the buffers appear. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea why a valuable answer/comment of a helpful user has disappeared. I will anwer it myself for sake of documentation without wanting to claim its content.

Answer (score 1):

Points themselves have no spatial extension. In the QGIS [buffer parameter definition](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#id13) for two dimensions one can see example lines with buffers of each end cap style applied. One can imagine the line buffer example without the line part in the middle as what would happen to a point.

For a point with only one dimension and no end cap there is no buffer to be drawn.
This is why a buffer can be created for round or squared end caps but not for flat end caps.

[image]